# Service API session vs Web UI Session

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc-4, backend, session-state

Little Background:

I have both ASP.Net MVC Service API and WebUI project written in C# under same solution.
And I am using SQL Server Session mode. (FYI, all sessions are stored and looks good to proceed with development)

Now, Session is good when Service API is called separately using
browser or postman

http://localhost/ServiceAPI/api/user/setContext

http://localhost/ServiceAPI/api/user/getContext

But the thing is when I call ServiceAPI using WebUI which is an angular app , the session is now null and so Session Key is 0.

Here is my code sample:

Controller:

```
    [Route("getContext")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetJson()
    {
        var sessionResult=_sessionManager.Get<LocalObjectStore>("UserSessionContext");
        return Ok(sessionResult);
    }

    [Route("setContext")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SetJson()
    {
        LocalObjectStore _storeObj = new LocalObjectStore
        {
            UserID = "DUMMY USERID 222",
            UserGuid = "DUMMY GUID",
            UserRole = "DUMMY ROLE",
            AssignedAuthToken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            IsAuthenticated = true,
            FE_SessionID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            BE_SessionID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            RestrictPages = new List<string> { "DUMMY Admin" }
        };

        _sessionManager.Set<LocalObjectStore>("UserSessionContext", _storeObj);

        return Ok("Updated");
    }
```

Session Interface and Class:

```
 public interface ISessionManager
{
    T Get<T>(string key);
    void Set<T>(string key, T entry);
}

public class SessionManager : ISessionManager
{
    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        HttpContext currentContext = GetSessionContext();

        return (T)currentContext.Session[key];
    }

    public void Set<T>(string key, T entry)
    {
        HttpContext currentContext = GetSessionContext();
        currentContext.Session[key] = entry;
    }

    private static HttpContext GetSessionContext()
    {
        HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;

        if (currentContext == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        return currentContext;
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs :

```
 protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
    {
        if (IsWebApiRequest())
        {
            HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
        }
    }

    private bool IsWebApiRequest()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith("~/api");
    }
```

dependency (using IUnityContainer):

```
container.RegisterType<ISessionManager, SessionManager>();
```

Lets see Browser now:

[here I am setting up the Session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYOTz.png)

[here I am getting saved Session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnWWx.png)

[and here is the session token Service API creates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldQyO.png)

but when I call from Web UI for example Login form, it stores objects in the Session, and when redirected to profile to update it looses the session.

Please help on this situation and save my hair.

**Thank you in advance.**